# Prolog issue with max list function: nondeterm vs procedure

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I am trying to do a small project in prolog where a user can input a list and then it calculates the average, max in the list etc. etc.

So far so good, but I ran into a problem when writing the max function (finds max number in the list). The code is:

```
maxN([X],X):-!.
maxN([X|L],X) :- maxN(L,M), X > M.
maxN([X|L],M) :- maxN(L,M), M >= X.
```

The function itself works separately, but I get this error message:

The predicate 'forma::maxN/2 (i,o)', which is declared as 'procedure', is actually 'nondeterm'  forma.pro

This is my predicate in the *.cl definition:

maxN: (integer* Z, integer U) procedure (i,o).

I cannot declare it as nondeterm because it causes issues with my whole form. Can you help me/give a hint how to make it a procedure? I am thinking I have to make a cut somewhere but my attempts have failed so far.

P.S. I am using Visual Prolog 7.4.

Edit: After trying the alternatives proposed to make the two rules into one or with an accumulator, I now get that the predicate is 'determ' instead of a procedure. According to my Prolog guide that means that the predicate doesn't have multiple solutions now, but instead has a chance to fail. Basically all code variations I've done up to now lead me to a 'determ'.

Comment: You should include the dialect in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I fixed the 'determ' thing by adding:

    maxN([], Max) :- Max=0,!.

Now, I know this is technically not very right to do, but since my program checks for an empty list (basically,  maxN([], Max) will never ever be called, and is there just for completeness of the rules, it works for me. Thank you both for the suggestions, they put me in the right direction!

Comment: It can still fail if you pass something besides a list in the first argument. If you still want to "fix" that (I wouldn't) you can provide another rule of the form `maxN(X, undefined) :- \+ is_list(X).`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll definitely add that, I am usually very paranoid about the inputs when writing in other languages, but being a Prolog newbie, I did not know this way of "checking".

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I am usually happy to let predicates fail on unexpected inputs. I consider it leveraging a strength of Prolog, though the debugging scenario that leaves you with is tracing. Then again, you wind up tracing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Prolog sees a choice point between your second and third rules. In other words, you, the human, know that both `X > M` and `M >= X` cannot both be true, but Prolog is not able to infer that.

IMO the best thing to do would be to rephrase those two rules with one rule:

```
maxN([X], X) :- !.
maxN([X|L], Max) :- 
   maxN(L, M), 
   X > M -> Max = X
          ; Max = M.
```

This way there isn't ever an extra choice point that would need to be pruned with a cut.

Following @CapelliC's advice, you could also reformulate this with an accumulator:

```
maxN([X|Xs], Max) :- maxN_loop(Xs, X, Max).

maxN_loop([], Max, Max).
maxN_loop([X|Xs], Y, Max) :- 
   X > Y -> maxN_loop(Xs, X, Max)
          ; maxN_loop(Xs, Y, Max).
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, Daniel, and sorry for not mentioning the dialect! As you can probably see, I am a bit new to all things Prolog.

Comment: That's fine. This is a great place to get help, but I should mention that nobody here has extensive experience with Visual Prolog specifically. You will find it much easier to get help here if you switch to SWI-Prolog or GNU Prolog.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Btw, I accidentally pressed enter before entering my whole response. I meant to say what I did with your suggestions:

I actually tried rephrasing the rules with one before, but then instead of 'nondeterm' I got that maxN was 'determ' which also gives an error.As far as my Prolog guide says, determ means that the predicate won't give multiple solution but there is an option that it will fail.I tried the Acc suggestion you and CapelliC gave,but it also led me to a 'determ'.But anyway thanks, you pointed me in the right direction and I'll continue to untangle the mysteries of Prolog!

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I don't know the Prolog dialect you're using, my advice is to try to add a cut after the second clause:

```
maxN([X|L],X) :- maxN(L,M), X > M, !.
```

Generally, I think a recursive procedure can be made deterministic transforming it to tail recursive. Unfortunately, this requires to add an accumulator:

```
maxN([],A,A).
maxN([X|L],A,M) :- X > A, !, maxN(L,X,M).
maxN([X|L],A,M) :- maxN(L,A,M).
```

Of course, top level call should become

```
maxN([F|L],M) :- maxN(L,F,M).
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions CapelliC!